# Sort nested list by a fixed order

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list like this one:

`list={{{a,1},{b,3},{c,5}},{{b,1},{c,3},{a,5}},{{c,1},{b,3},{a,5}},{{a,1},{c,3},{b,5}}}`

Now I need to sort the list such that the order within a row is always {{a,..},{b,..},{c,..}}. Put differently: the order of the first elements within the sublists should always be a, b and then c.

Comment: `SortBy[First] /@ list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[sortLike]
sortLike[refcolumn_, orderlike_] := 
 Map[#[[Ordering[#[[All, refcolumn]]][[Ordering @ Ordering @ orderlike]]]] &]
```

***Examples:***

```
list = {{{a, 1}, {b, 3}, {c, 5}}, {{b, 1}, {c, 3}, {a, 5}}, 
   {{c, 1}, {b, 3}, {a, 5}}, {{a, 1}, {c, 3}, {b, 5}}};


sortLike[1, {a, b, c}]@list // Column
```

[image]

```
sortLike[1, {b, a, c}]@list // Column
```

[image]

```
sortLike[2, {1, 2, 10}]@list // Column
```

[image]

```
sortLike[2, {5, 1, 3}]@list // Column
```

[image]

The argument `orderlike` can be given alternative ways to get the same result:

```
Multicolumn[Labeled[Column[sortLike[1, #]@list], 
    Row[{"orderlike: ", Style[#, ShowStringCharacters -> True]}], Top] & /@ 
 {{c, a, b}, {"c", "a", "b"}, {"FOO", "BAR", "BUZZ"}, {3, 1, 2}, 
  {100, 0, 25}, foo[10, 1, 9]}, 3,
 Dividers -> All, Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! That way it is general.

Answer (score 6):

Something like the following:

```
Map[Sort[#] &, list]
(*{{{a, 1}, {b, 3}, {c, 5}}, {{a, 5}, {b, 1}, {c, 3}}, {{a, 5}, {b, 3}, {c, 1}}, {{a, 1}, {b, 5}, {c, 3}}}*)
```

A first approximation:

```
MyOrderList[list_List, order_?(Positive[#] && Element[#, Integers] &)] := 
Block[{slist, perm, mylist},
slist := Map[Sort, list];
perm = Mean[Map[Composition[Length, Permutations[#] &], slist]];
mylist := 
Table[Table[Extract[Select[Tuples[slist[[i]], Length[slist[[i]]]], 
ContainsAll[#, slist[[i]]] &], j], {i, 1, Length[slist]}], {j, 1, perm}][[order]];
Return[If[order <= perm, mylist, HoldForm[MyOrderList]]];
];

Tests:

MyOrderList[list, 1]
(*{{{a, 1}, {b, 3}, {c, 5}}, {{a, 5}, {b, 1}, {c, 3}}, {{a, 5}, 
  {b, 3}, {c, 1}}, {{a, 1}, {b, 5}, {c, 3}}}*)
MyOrderList[list, 2]
(*{{{a, 1}, {c, 5}, {b, 3}}, {{a, 5}, {c, 3}, {b, 1}}, {{a, 5}, 
  {c, 1}, {b, 3}}, {{a, 1}, {c, 3}, {b, 5}}}*)
MyOrderList[list, 3]
(*{{{b, 3}, {a, 1}, {c, 5}}, {{b, 1}, {a, 5}, {c, 3}}, {{b, 3}, 
  {a, 5}, {c, 1}}, {{b, 5}, {a, 1}, {c, 3}}}*)
MyOrderList[list,4]
(*{{{b, 3}, {c, 5}, {a, 1}}, {{b, 1}, {c, 3}, {a, 5}}, {{b, 3}, 
  {c, 1}, {a, 5}}, {{b, 5}, {c, 3}, {a, 1}}}*)
MyOrderList[list,5]
(*{{{c, 5}, {a, 1}, {b, 3}}, {{c, 3}, {a, 5}, {b, 1}}, {{c, 1}, 
  {a, 5}, {b, 3}}, {{c, 3}, {a, 1}, {b, 5}}}*)
MyOrderList[list,6]
(*{{{c, 5}, {b, 3}, {a, 1}}, {{c, 3}, {b, 1}, {a, 5}}, {{c, 1}, 
  {b, 3}, {a, 5}}, {{c, 3}, {b, 5}, {a, 1}}}*)
```

Another approach using the idea of [@cvgmt](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258525/a-question-about-ordering-command/258528#258528):

```
  MyOrderList[list_List, order_List] := 
  Block[{slist, sorder, ordering, mylist},
  slist := Map[Sort, list];
  ordering := 
  Extract[Permute[Ordering[Sort[order]], Ordering[#]] & /@ 
  Permutations[order], {1}];(*@cvgmt*)
  mylist := Table[slist[[i]][[ordering]], {i, 1, Length[slist]}];
  Return[mylist];
   ];
```

Test:

```
MyOrderList[list, {b, c, a}]
(*{{{b, 3}, {c, 5}, {a, 1}}, {{b, 1}, {c, 3}, {a, 5}}, {{b, 3}, 
  {c, 1}, {a, 5}}, {{b, 5}, {c, 3}, {a, 1}}}*)
```

Another approach using the idea of [@kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/258525/a-question-about-ordering-command/258528#258528):

```
 MyOrderList[list_List, order_List] := 
 Block[{slist, sorder, ordering, mylist},
 slist := Map[Sort, list];
 ordering := 
 Extract[Map[Ordering@*Ordering, Permutations[order]], {1}];(*@kglr*)
 mylist := Table[slist[[i]][[ordering]], {i, 1, Length[slist]}];
 Return[mylist];
   ];
```

Test:

```
MyOrderList[list, {c, a, b}]
(*{{{c, 5}, {a, 1}, {b, 3}}, {{c, 3}, {a, 5}, {b, 1}}, {{c, 1}, 
  {a, 5}, {b, 3}}, {{c, 3}, {a, 1}, {b, 5}}}*)
```

Comment: This can be abbreviated by noting that `Map[Sort[#] &, list] === Map[Sort, list] === Sort /@ list`

Comment: This is all very nice but now lets assume I want the order to be ```{{b,..},{c,..},{a,..}}```?? Is there a way to define a fixed predefined order? I'm sorry my question was not exact enough. I used ```a```, ```b``` and ```c``` to keep it very simple.. e.g. the first elements could also be some text strings...

Comment: @M.A. ``ReplaceAll[Thread[{a, b, c} -> {b, c, a}]][Map[Sort, list]]``

Comment: @E.Chan-López This changes the structure of the list!! Besides this, your code does not work if you replace ```a```, ```b```,```c``` with strings...

Comment: @E.Chan-López: the first code in your answer produces NOT the same result as your function

Comment: @M.A. You're right. I'll think about it a little more.