# A question about Ordering command

Tags: list-manipulation

We have the following list:

```
list={a,b,c};
```

Subsequently, we apply the `Ordering` command to the permutations of the previous list, and we obtain the following:

```
Permutations[{a, b, c}]
(*{{a, b, c}, {a, c, b}, {b, a, c}, {b, c, a}, {c, a, b}, {c, b, a}}*)
Map[Ordering, Permutations[{a, b, c}]]
(*{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 2}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 2, 1}}*)
```

The order of the first three items in the output list is correct, but the following provide an incorrect order.

Someone to help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
per = Permutations[{a, b, c}]
Permute[{1, 2, 3}, Ordering[#]] & /@ per
```

> {{a,b,c},{a,c,b},{b,a,c},{b,c,a},{c,a,b},{c,b,a}}

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks a lot, cvgmt :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Map[Ordering @* Ordering, Permutations[{a, b, c}]]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {2, 1, 3}, {2, 3, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Your answers are always excellent, kglr. Thanks a lot :)